# Select from where like % string % or like % string %

Tags: php, mysql

As title, which is the correct syntax for

```
$query = "SELECT id, codice, cod_forn, ubicazione, descrizione, package, quantita 
          FROM maglab 
          WHERE (codice LIKE '%" . $cod_cercato . "%')
          OR (ubicazione LIKE '%" . $ubic_cercato . "%')
          OR (descrizione LIKE '%" . $descr_cercato . "%')";
```

I have 6 input textbox and a search button

```
<form method="post" action="magazzinoNew.php">
    <input type="text" name="codice" placeholder="Codice " />
    <input type="text" name="codice_forn" placeholder="Codice fornitore" />
    <input type="text" name="ubicazione" placeholder="Ubicazione " />
    <input type="text" name="descrizione" placeholder="Descrizione " />
    <input type="text" name="package" placeholder="Package " />
    <input type="text" name="quantita" placeholder="Quantita " />
    <input type="submit" name="cerca" value="CERCA"  /><br /><br />
</form>
```

if i only use

```
$query = "SELECT id, codice, cod_forn, ubicazione, descrizione, package, quantita 
          FROM maglab 
          WHERE (codice LIKE '%" . $cod_cercato . "%')";
```

the search works fine, but when i add more items with OR the search don't work and the table show the entire database instead of the searched item

Comment: If any field is left blank, then the OR will mean it matches all of the blank fields (as it checks against `'%%'`)

Comment: Also, take care of SQL injection.

Comment: @Nigel Ren so what can i do?